# Javascript Closure with setInterval() in React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, react-hooks

In the following example, I expect the count value will increase in console as in UI. However, it doesn't, the value is always 0, but the value increase in UI. I know the issue might be related to Javascript Closure. In my understanding, the `count` should refer to the value in `useState`. Since the `count` is updated by `setCount`, the value keeps increase. However, why it doesn't increase in the log?
Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-fermat-42lxq?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function innerFunction() {
    return () => {
      console.log("count: ", count);
      setCount(c => c + 1);
    };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(innerFunction(), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);
  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that inside the setInterval callback, the value of count does not change, because we’ve created a closure with the value of count set to 0 as it was when the effect callback ran

At first render, the closure log() captures count variable as 0. Later, even if count increases, log() still uses count as 0 from initial render. log() is a stale closure.

The solution is to let know useEffect() that the closure log() depends on count and properly handle the reset of interval:

**Add count as dependency in useEffect**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(innerFunction(), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [count]);
```

With the dependencies properly set, useEffect() updates the closure as soon as count changes.

**Explanation**

**In the absence of dependencies**, useEffect() is called only initially. It will not be re-called.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("is re-rendering");
    const id = setInterval(innerFunction(), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);
```

Here, "**is re-rendering**" is logged only once.

If you use this syntax for setting state instead of functional syntax(which fetch latest count state). It also shows behavior as log as stale closure

```
setCount( count + 1); //always 1 as it gets 0 as count value
```

Since **useEffect** is not called after **count** changes, they take same initial input and give same initial output as they doesnot know about a changes.

**If we add count as dependency** then **useEffect** is re-called whenever **count** value changes and **setInterval** is also re-initialized with new updated input.

**More Info**

https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

**Example**

I have shown a similar issue with simple example.

Here,I have changed the value of outerVar(let us consider it is like a **count** state) after first calling outerfn.

But its updated changes is not reflected. This is how closure work.

```js
let outerVar='initial-outer'
function outerfn(outerVar){
  return function innerfn(innerVar){
     console.log('outer variable: '+ outerVar)
     console.log('inner variable: '+ innerVar)
     }
 }
 
 let newfn=outerfn(outerVar)
 outerVar="updated-outer" // outerVal is now changed
 newfn('inside') // but initial outerVal is printed here

 newfn=outerfn(outerVar)//resetting closure with updated value (like adding dependency to useEffect)
 newfn('inside') // updated outerVal is printed now
```

Comment: I don't understand `the closure log() captures count variable as 0`. Could you give me more explanation?

Comment: i have updated my answer. Hope it makes more clear :)

Comment: Thank you for updating the explanation. Why the count value is not updated when we keep calling `setCount()`? Why `console.log("count: ", count);` doesn't get the updated count?

Comment: count is updated by setCount() . But function provided to setInterval is not re-initialized to know the updated value of count.

Comment: Is it because `count` is immutable when using React Hook? To be more specific, `console.log("count: ", count);` is set in first render, so the `count` is 0. Even though the `count` has been updated, the new `count` is not the `count` in the first render. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The problem is that inside the setInterval callback, the value of count does not change, because we’ve created a closure with the value of count set to 0 as it was when the effect callback first ran.

Comment: you can go through this.It talks in more depth of diferent strategies.  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Comment: I have provided an example in my answer. Hope this helps you understand more clearly :)

Comment: Just one correction, when you are talking about closure, it is the innerFunction function, not log(), since the name of the function above is innerFunction.